# const char * ptr vs char ptr []

Tags: c++, pointers, c-strings

I am passing a string constant from main to a function, My question was why there is an error when I put an array of characters (cstring) in the function argument but it works alright when I put constant character pointer, isn't an array a constant pointer ??
Here is the function (it is actually a parametrized constructor for my string class)

```
String (   const char * str )
        {
            size = strlen(str);
            arr = new char [size] // arr and size are my data members
            for ( int i = 0 ; i<size ; i++)
                arr[i] = str[i];
        }
```

Comment: Arrays are not pointers. Duplicate hundreds of times over.

Comment: You are not allocating for or copying `str`'s terminating character.

Comment: You didn't include an error message and the inputs which cause the issue.

Comment: The question is a mess. You can't just say "there is an error". Do you mean there is an error inside the `String` constructor we see here? Or do you mean there is error elsewhere in your code at the location where you create a `String` object and call this constructor? And why are you trying (with bugs) to create a `String` object anyway, when `std:: string` exists

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Unless the pointer was explicitly defined to be constant (`const`) the pointer to the array is not constant but just a regular pointer, thus can be modified
2. The above code is buggy as arr should be of len [size + 1] to save space for the terminating zero (end of string char)